# Does Heine-Borel hold for smooth manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, the famous Whitney embedding theorems show that we can view $M$ as an embedded submanifold of some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Does the Heine-Borel theorem still hold for subsets of $M$? I.e., is $S\subseteq M$ compact iff $S$ is closed in $M$, and bounded in the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: The [Hopf-Rinow Theorem][1] establishes equivalent conditions for a Riemannian manifold to have the Heine-Borel property.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For example, if $M=(0,1)$, then $M$ is closed in itself and embeds boundedly in $\Bbb{R}$, but is not compact.

If $M$ were embedded as a closed submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^N$, the result you want would follow immediately. But there's no guarantee that $M$ has a closed embedding in $\Bbb{R}^N$ just because it has an embedding in $\Bbb{R}^N$.